# How we code attributes in json with java

Tags: java, xml, json

In XML, we have attributes inside tags

```
<x attributename="y"> Abcd </x>
```

How we code attributes in json with java

For example:

```
{
  "AAAA": {
    "-BBBB": "01-1-2011",
    "-CCCC": "11:11",
    "Data": [
      {
        "EE": "1111",
        "FF": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

if we put the json code in this website
http://jsontoxml.utilities-online.info/
and we convert it to xml we will find:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <AAAA BBBB="01-1-2011" CCCC="11:11">
        <Data>
            <EE>1111</EE>
            <FF>1</FF>
        </Data>
    </AAAA>
```

So how could we code the 'BBBB' and 'CCCC' with java

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

There are no "attributes" in JSON, there are keys, values, arrays and objects.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, attributes are in XML. You don't do that in JSON, as it's not part of the format.

Answer (score 0):

As ahanin has said, JSON doesn't have attributes.  You could, however, establish your own convention:

```
{
  "AAAA": {
    "attributes" : {
        "-BBBB": "01-1-2011",
        "-CCCC": "11:11"
         },
    "Data": [
      {
        "EE": "1111",
        "FF": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

although it seems a bit pointless to me.  Attributes are just an alternative way of expressing key-value pairs and are not necessary even in XML.